# How to send wav data from As3 to Javascript using ExternalInterface?

Tags: javascript, encoding, actionscript, decoding

Does any one know how to send wav data from As3 to JavaScript using ExternalInterface?

Currently I have a wav-encoded data and when I am sending using ExternalInterface to JavaScript function that wav Array become JavaScript Object. And nothing in it.

I also try to encode that data to base64 String and send it to javascript function. But JavaScript can not decode it properly it display chunk character.

Comment: wav data is that a byte array you trying to send across ?

Comment: Yes, its a byte Array.

Comment: you can convert it as a base64 string and send it across. But still it depend on what you have to do with that byte array.

Comment: *it display chunk character...* - what does that mean? Encoding it as Base64 is the correct way to go. You should have no problems decode it in JS.

Comment: when i convert it to base64 string and decode using js and save it not getting sound. when i see the decoded string its display chunk character over there?

Comment: What is the way that i geeting properly decoded data? any JS you know? send me a name of JS Which decode wavBas64 String properly.

Comment: I am able to save this file to using following Function

Comment: var appheader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
                
      var jpgUrlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest( 'http://localhost/RecordingApp/saveSound.php' );
                
      jpgUrlRequest.requestHeaders.push( appheader );
      jpgUrlRequest.method = "POST";
      jpgUrlRequest.data = _oggManager.wavBytes;
   var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.load( jpgUrlRequest );

Comment: php code <?php
if( isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) )
{
    $name = 'zvuk_' . '.wav';
    
    $f = fopen( $name, 'w+');
    
    if( fwrite( $f, $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] ) )
    {
        echo $name;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 0;
    }
    
    fclose($f);    
}
?>